# How to delete BLOBs from MySQL database without deleting the whole row?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called `config` with 5 columns, the structure is like follows:

```
 config_id | product_id | color_id | preview_front | preview_back
-----------+------------+----------+---------------+--------------
  int(11)  |  int(11)   | int(11)  |    BLOB       |   BLOB
```

The 2 BLOB columns have the attribute "BINARY" set. They contain 150x150 pixel preview images, each with a file size of roughly 6 KB.

My question is simple: How can I delete / remove the BLOBs without deleting the entire row?

Please note: Deleting the row is not an option. We need the data from the first 3 columns and are legally obliged to keep them. But we'd like to free up some space on our servers and approximately 1 GB of old and unused images seems like a good place to start.

I've already tried changing the column properties in PHPMyAdmin (version 3.4.10.1) to allow NULL values but I got an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Would something simple like `UPDATE table SET preview_front='' WHERE ...` work?

Comment: Looks like it might, thanks a lot! :) The estimated size shown for the BLOB is now 0 bytes. Didn't think it might be as simple as that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply run an `UPDATE` query and set the BLOB fields to `''`.

```
UPDATE table SET preview_front='', preview_back=''
WHERE config_id = 1
```

Comment: if the table is a MyISAM table you would need to optimize the table to claim the disk space.

Answer (score 1):

or like that
UPDATE `table` 
SET `preview_front`=NULL, `preview_back`=NULL
WHERE `config_id` = 1

Comment: Please format your code correctly and write some explaination to it.